# How does one save a variable in a Tab for use with one's Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am writing an extension that opens new tabs and I need to save the value of a var in the current tab, such that it will exist even if the user restarts Firefox. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use nsIPrefService and [nsIPrefBranch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIPrefBranch).

Something like:

```
// Get pref service.
nsresult rv;
nsCOMPtr<nsIPrefService> service(do_GetService(NS_PREFSERVICE_CONTRACTID, &rv));
NS_ENSURE_SUCCESS(rv, false);

// Get your extensions branch.
nsCOMPtr<nsIPrefBranch> branch;
service->GetBranch("extensions.YOUREXTENSION.", getter_AddRefs(branch));
NS_ENSURE_SUCCESS(rv, false);
```

Then you can use GetCharPref() and SetCharPref().

```
// Get value
char *buf = nsnull;
rv = branch->GetCharPref("YOURPREF", &buf);
```

To clear a pref, I suspect you would use [clearUserPref()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIPrefBranch#clearUserPref.28.29).